# Kops/Kubernetes how to add simple image to the cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kops

pretty new to kubernetes/kops, I have followed the tutorial for kops on aws, and I have created a cluster. I'd like to run a very simple container from hub.docker on the cluster, how do I go about adding this container to the cluster? Is it in the cluster config file or will I need to add another image to the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes, container could be run as Pod, which is a resource in Kubernetes.

You could prepare a yaml or json file to create your pod with command `kubectl create -f $yourfile`

Example could be found here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/javaweb-tomcat-sidecar/javaweb.yaml

And for images by default, Kubernetes will pull images from Docker Hub, if not existing in your cluster, and also depends on your `ImagePullPolicy`

You just need to specify your image at section `spec.containers.image`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. For example to run the nginx web server in your cluster you can use the command line below, this will download image from docker hub and start the instance.

   kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80

Here is command https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.8/.

To run your image change the nginx with your image name.

2. Other option is to create the deployment yaml file and run the container.

> ```
> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:  
>   labels:
>     run: nginx
>   name: nginx 
> spec:
>   replicas: 2
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       run: nginx
>   strategy:
>     rollingUpdate:
>       maxSurge: 1
>       maxUnavailable: 1
>     type: RollingUpdate
>   template:
>     metadata:     
>       labels:
>         run: nginx
>         tier: frontend
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - image: nginx:1.10
>         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
>         name: nginx
>         lifecycle:
>             preStop:
>               exec:
>                 command: ["/usr/sbin/nginx","-s","quit"]    
>       restartPolicy: Always      
>       terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
> ```

store above file in `nginx.yaml` file then run it with kubectl command.

`kubectl create -f nginx.yaml`